# For Loop and DML Inside

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a class that I call from a trigger with this code below.

Below is what I want to do and is meant to be psuedo code.

```
public static void updateSalePrice( List<OpportunityLineItem> productList) {

   for( OpportunityLineItem ol : productList ) {
  
    Pricing_Data__c = [SELECT Id, CPU__c, CPU_Speed__c, Price__c FROM Pricing_Data__c 
    WHERE CPU__c = ol.CPU_Speed__c AND CPU_Speed__c = ol.CPU_Speed__c];

  }

}
```

The productList that gets passed in is a list of opportunity product records.  I have two custom fields on the Opportunity Product object, CPU__c and CPU_Speed__c. I want to use these 2 fields to make a query to the Pricing Data custom object.  There is no relationship between these objects, the combination of CPU__c and CPU_Speed__c are unique on this object.

I am struggling with how to write this so it's bulkified.  I may have multiple productList records coming in.

How can I rewrite this to avoid having the DML as I do.

Comment: First you need to loop through the OLIs and collect all CPU and CPU Speed values into two Sets.  After that, select all Pricing Data records that have those values and create Map(s) as needed.  Then you loop through all the OLIs again and process each record based on your maps.

Comment: What have you tried so far to bulkify it?  What part of it are you getting stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

Since the combination of CPU and CPU Speed is unique, you may consider to create a formula field which function as a composite key, eg `CPU_with_Speed__c`

To bring your Pricing Data query out of loop, store it in a Map with the composite key.

```java
Set<String> cpuWithSpeed = new Set<String>();
for (OpportunityLineItem ol : productList) {
   cpuWithSpeed.add(ol.CPU__c + ol.CPU_Speed__c);
}

Map<String, Pricing_Data__c> pricingData = new Map<String, Pricing_Data__c>();
for (Pricing_Data__c pd : [SELECT .. FROM Pricing_Data__c 
        WHERE CPU_with_Speed__c = :cpuWithSpeed]) {
    pricingData.put(pd.CPU_with_Speed__c, pd);
}
```

Reference the pricing data with the composite key:

```java
for (OpportunityLineItem ol : productList) {
    Pricing_Data__c pd = pricingData.get(ol.CPU__c + ol.CPU_Speed__c);
}
```